# ListView - Mostrar en template estructura aunque esté vacío

Tags: python, django, listview, viewmodel

Estoy creando una plataforma completa en django pero me he encontrado con un problema que no entiendo muy bien.

He intentado con queryset pasar el modelo pero no consigo pintar la estructura de la tabla, aunque esta no tenga registros y ya no se si precisamente es por ésto.

Solo consigo pintar que no hay registros.

El model:

```
class Activities(models.Model):
    HORAS = [
        (0, '0'),
        (1, '1'),
        (2, '2'),
        (3, '3'),
        (4, '4'),
        (5, '5'),
        (6, '6'),
        (7, '7'),
        (8, '8'),
    ]
    MINUTOS = [
        (0, '0'),
        (15, '15'),
        (30, '30'),
        (45, '45'),
    ]

    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True, db_index=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name='Usuario', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    destiny = models.ForeignKey(Functions, verbose_name='Destino', blank=False, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    activity = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Actividad', default=0, help_text='Actividad realizada DENTRO de \
                                                                                    los plazos correspondientes.')
    sla = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Actividad en SLA', default=0, help_text='Actividad realizada FUERA de \
                                                                                    los plazos correspondientes.')
    comment = models.CharField(verbose_name='Comentario', max_length=500, blank=True)
    hours = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Horas', choices=HORAS, blank=False, unique=False, default=0)
    minutes = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Minutos', choices=MINUTOS, blank=False, unique=False, default=0)
    date = models.DateField(verbose_name='Fecha', blank=False, unique=False)
    date_reg = models.DateField(verbose_name='Fecha Registro', blank=False, unique=False)
    close = models.BooleanField(verbose_name='Cerrado', default=False, blank=False, unique=False)

    historical = HistoricalRecords()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Actividad'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Actividades'

    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['user', 'destiny', 'activity', 'sla',  'hours', 'minutes', 'date', 'date_reg']

    def natural_key(self):
        return self.id
```

la view:

```
class MensualActivities(ListView):
    allow_empty = True
    model = Activities
    template_name = "sox/base_sox.html"
    context_object_name = "activity"
```

el template:

```
        {% if activity %}
                
            {% for a in activity %}
                {{a.name}}
            {% endfor %}
        
        {% else %}
            No hay actividad
        {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Respondo a mi propia pregunta:

No estaba informando las cabeceras en la tabla html.

El template quedaría de la siguiente manera :

```
        {% if activity %}
        <table class="table">
            <tr>
                <th>USUARIO</U></th>
                <th>DESTINO</th>
                <th>HORAS</th>
                <th>MINUTOS</th>
                <th>ACTIVIDAD</th>
                <th>SLA</th>
            </tr>
            {% for a in activity %}
                <td>{{a.user}}</td>
                <td>{{a.destiny}}</td>
                <td>{{a.hours}}</td>
                <td>{{a.minutes}}</td>
                <td>{{a.activity}}</td>
                <td>{{a.sla}}</td>
            {% endfor %}
        </table>
        {% else %}
            No hay actividad
        {% endif %}
```

Comment: Si, lo intenté pero me dijo que 2 días :)
Gracias por el aviso igualmente!!!